# compiling ptx code on NVIDIA GPU?

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, nvidia, ptxas

I want to intercept at PTX level of opencl programs on NVIDIA GPU.

I imagine the routine would probably look like this.

First, I write an opencl program (both host and device code), using NVIDIA compiler to produce respective ptx code. Then I write what I want to do by modifying the PTX code (please don't ask why I didn't do this on the device C code - I have some reasons for it). But problem is, after being modified, how do I compile this PTX code to binary code?

Comment: Use the CUDA toolchain and CUDA driver API. I don't believe there is a way to deal with assembly code or inline assembler instruction with OpenCL.

Comment: This works for CUDA http://wili.cc/blog/ptx.html. Might work for OpenCL too

Answer (score 1):

You can use ptxas, which is included in the CUDA toolkit. It compiles .ptx into .cubin, which can then be loaded with the driver API.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to re-inject the PTX into OpenCL.  You could use the CUDA Driver API and cuModuleLoadData. If you really need to do this low level of PTX manipulation, I recommend you just use CUDA (and possibly the [CUDA Compiler SDK (libNVVM)](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-llvm-compiler).